# Split a string using regex into 3 parts

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string like this

```
DATA/2019-00-01-23.x
```

I want to get three tokens Text, Date and Hour

```
[DATA, 2019-00-01, 23]
```

I tried this

```
String x = "DATA/2019-00-01-23.x";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x.split("/|-[0-9]+.")))
```

This returns me

```
[DATA, 2019, 01, x]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution 1

You can replace the last part after the dot, then using split with [`/|(\-)(?!.*\-)`](https://regex101.com/r/gsne6z/1) :

```
String[] split = "DATA/2019-00-01-23.x".replaceFirst("\\..*$", "")
    .split("/|(\\-)(?!.*\\-)"); // [DATA, 2019-00-01, 23]
```

### Solution 2

I would go with `Pattern` and `Matcher` and groups like so [`(.*?)/(.*?)-([^-]+)\\..*`](https://regex101.com/r/Vu9wXI/1) :

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?)/(.*?)-([^-]+)\\..*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("DATA/2019-00-01-23.x");
if(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); // DATA
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2)); // 2019-00-01
    System.out.println(matcher.group(3)); // 23
}
```

---

Or by using Java9+ you can use :

```
String[] result = Pattern.compile("(.*?)/(.*?)-([^-]+)\\..*")
        .matcher("DATA/2019-00-01-23.x")
        .results()
        .flatMap(grps -> Stream.of(grps.group(1), grps.group(2), grps.group(3)))
        .toArray(String[]::new);
```

**Outputs**

```
[DATA, 2019-00-01, 23]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may actually use a `split` like

```
x.split("/|-(?=[^-]*$)|\\D+$")
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/KSqZBy), output: `[DATA, 2019-00-01, 23]`.

This regex will split at

- `/` - a slash
- `|` - or
- `-(?=[^-]*$)` - last hyphen in the string
- `|` - or
- `\D+$` - any 1+ non-digit chars at the end of the string (as `String.split(regex)` is run with `limit` argument as `0`, these matches at the end of the string do not result in trailing empty items in the resulting array.)

Answer (score 0):

Use capturing groups to extract the three parts.

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(.+)/([-0-9]+)-([0-9]{1,2})\\..*");

public static void main(String... args) {
    Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher("DATA/2019-00-01-23.x");

    if (matcher.matches() && matcher.groupCount() == 3) {
        String text = matcher.group(1);
        String date = matcher.group(2);
        String hour = matcher.group(3);
        System.out.println(text + "\t" + date + '\t' + hour);
    }
}
```

Dissected: `(.+)` `/` `([-0-9]+)` `-` `([0-9]{2})` `\..*`

- `(.+)` Everything before the `/`
- `([-0-9]+)` Numbers, can contain `-`
- `-` to prevent the previous part from gobbling up the hour
- `([0-9]{2})` Two numbers
- `\..*` A period, then 'the rest'.